# LESS: create variables in a way similar to 'nested rules'

Tags: less

Actually I have several LESS variables defined in the following way:

```
@toolbar-first-level-item-color-background:             @transparent-black-80;
@toolbar-first-level-item-color-background_hover:       @black;
@toolbar-second-level-item-color-background:            lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background,30%);
@toolbar-second-level-item-color-background_hover:      lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background_hover,30%);
@toolbar-third-level-item-color-background:             lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background,40%);
@toolbar-third-level-item-color-background_hover:       lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background_hover,40%);
@toolbar-fourth-level-item-color-background:            lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background,45%);
@toolbar-fourth-level-item-color-background_hover:      lighten(@toolbar-entry-color-background_hover,45%);
```

As you can see, there are several repetitions in it, so I wonder if could be possible to use something like namespaces or maps to create a more compact and less repetitive declaration.

The idea is starting by structure of nested rules, that create a very clear hierarchy with few repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use a [map](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature). It is a new feature in Less lang that allows you to get values using keys.

You can write something like that:

```
@toolbar: {
  @first-level-item: {
    color-background: #fff;
  };
}

text {
  color: @toolbar[@first-level-item][color-background];
}
```

Comment: uhmmm not so bad... surely a solution at which I neve thought... anyway, just a thing does not convince me completely... property definition at the beginning. As you can imagine, my current code is in a "variables.less" file and... I don't like so much to insert a property inside it... generally, only variables in it... so maybe could be better to replace also `color-background` with `@color-background`

Comment: Anyway... in this case could be almost near to a possible solution but... how to improve nesting? I'd like to use "concatenation" also in variables name, for example looking at `@first-level-item`, obviously I'll have also `@second-level-item` and so on... could be interesting to write something similar to `@level-item{&-first}` (in comments I don't have indentention.. damn) to concatenate only variable part of names